# Logical Proof And Separation of Implicit Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

Working on a logic proof with the criteria:

---

$ax + by = 2$ where $x$ and $y$ are some integer $> 0$

$d\mid a$, $d\mid bc$ where $d$ is an odd divisor of $a$

Prove that $d\mid c$

---

I've now created the expression:

\begin{align}
& d\mid a \therefore a = kd \\
& d\mid bc \therefore bc = ld \to b = \frac{ld}{c} \\
& xkd + \frac{yld}{c} = 2
\end{align}

All I'd need to do to complete this proof is to arrange the equation in the form $c = f(x,y,k,l)d$, however, I haven't been able to come up with a way to do that, and am not sure if it's possible. If it *is* possible to arrange the equation in this form, I'd appreciate even a first step in doing so. If it's *not* possible to do so, where would I have gone wrong in my logic to arrive at an impossible solution?

Answer (score -1):

Hint: let $e = \gcd(d, b)\,$, then $e \mid d \mid a$ and $e \mid b$ implies $e \mid ax+by=2\,$. But $d$ is odd, so it cannot have $2$ as a factor, therefore $e=1\,$ so $d$ and $b$ are coprime. Then $d \mid bc$ and $\gcd(d,b)=1 \implies \cdots$

> where would I have gone wrong in my logic to arrive at an impossible solution?

For one thing, you never used the premise that $d$ is odd.